# Extract String Between Two words in R

Tags: r, gsub, exact-match

Let's say this is my string

```
string<- c("righttoleftrightandleft")
```

I want to extract all the character between right and left so the result will be something like that

```
results<-("to","and")
```

Comment: This page may be of help: https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html

Comment: What if there are two words in between left and right? Would the desired output of `lefttotherightand` be `[1] "tothe" "and"` or `[1] "to" "the" "and"`? Unsure how you would do the latter.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this with `s <- "righttoleftrightandleft"`

```
strsplit(gsub("right(.*?)left", "\\1 ", s), split="\\s")[[1]]
```

This gives a vector:

```
[1] "to"  "and"
```

Note that:

1. `gsub` extracts all elements between parentheses, each stored in `\\1`
2. `?` is required for non-greedy match
3. `strsplit` splits the resulting match on whitespace

Answer (score 3):

Could try:

```
gsub("right(.*?)left", "\\1", regmatches(string, gregexpr("right(.*?)left",string))[[1]])
```

Where `regmatches(...)` returns matches sequences and `gsub(...)` extracts the word in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following:

```
text="righttoleftrightandleft"
A=unlist(strsplit(text,"right|left",))
A[A!=""]
[1] "to"  "and"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string<- c("righttoleftrightandleft")
vec <- strsplit(string, split = "left")

result <- c( sub(pattern = "right", "", vec[[1]][1:2]) )
```

Comment: The items returned must be between "right" and "left", if string is not as perfectly formed as the one in the example then your approach may not work.